# Query Firestore by value length

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

A question for the Firebase Firestore gurus out there.

I'm wanting to query a users collection for all documents where the `bio` field has a character length of `<n`

Is this possible?
I'm thinking this might have to be done post-query with some JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore can only order/filter on values that are stored in the documents it returns. It cannot calculate any values, nor look values up.

So if you want to filter on the length of the bio, you'll have to store that value in a field in the document (e.g. `bioLength`) and update that each time you also update the bio.

With that field in place, you can then filter on it in a query.